# Python: BeautifulSoup Web Parser, How do I scrape text without returning the html tags and Â

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, bots

So My code is returning html tags along with the symbol "Â" How can I delete all the html tags and the symbol 'Â'. I know for the symbol, I have to do something regarding the unicode.

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import izip

grant_number = ['0901289','0901282','0901260']
#IMPORTANT NOTE: PLACE GRANT NUMBERS BETWEEN STRINGS WITH NO SPACES

start = 'this site'
end = 'Please report errors'
#start and end show the words that come right before the publication data; This program will scrape for text in between these phrases
my_string = []
#my_string is an empty list for the publication data


for x in grant_number:      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "http://nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID={}".format(x)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    soup_string = str(soup)
    my_string.append(soup_string[(soup_string.index(start)+len(start)):soup_string.index(end)])
with open('NSF.csv', 'wb') as f:
    #Default Filename is NSF.csv ; This can be changed by editing the first field after 'open('
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(izip(grant_number, my_string))
#this imports the lists into a csv file with two columns, grant number on left, publication data on right
```

Comment: Â is an html entity converted to unicode https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the text (is not understandable for me why you want this) ... you should do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
soup_string = soup.text
```

If you want to strip the whitespaces do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
soup_string = soup.text.strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do this:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print soup.get_text()`

You should get something like this:

```
NSF Award Search: Award#0901289 - Rational points on elliptic curves over totally real fields and p-adic L-functions


    var printFlag = false;

    function printThisPage() {
    document.getElementById('printFriendly').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly5').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly51').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly6').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('printFriendly7').style.display='block';


    //if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    //  window.print();
    //}
    //else{

    //window.refresh();

    window.print();
    //}


    opener.printFlag = false;   }   function popwin(url)   {
     //alert('popwin url = ' + url);
     var hNewWnd = window.open(url,"","width=520,height=590,left=480,resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes");
     if ((document.window != null) && (!hNewWnd.opener))

       hNewWnd.opener = document.window;   }

    function printerFriendlyView()
     {  
     printFlag = true;
     var printerFriendlyViewWin = window.open(document.URL, "printerFriendlyViewWin","menubar=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,alwaysRaised=1,width=600,height=600,resizable=1");
     }
    Research Areas   Biological Sciences Computer & Information Science & Engineering Education and Human Resources Engineering Environmental Research & Education Geosciences Office of International & Integrative Activities Mathematical & Physical Sciences Social, Behavioral & Economic Sciences

    Learning Resources   Film, TV, Exhibits & More! Slideshows & Photo Galleries Classroom Resources Funding for Research on Learning in Formal & Informal Settings



    Funding & Awards Funding Info   Search Funding Opportunities Browse Funding Opportunities A-Z Recent Funding Opportunities How to Prepare a Funding Proposal Grant Proposal Guide Submit a Proposal to FastLane   Award Info   Managing Awards Award & Administration Guide Search Awards Award Statistics (Budget Internet Info System)

    News & Discoveries   Recent News Recent Discoveries Multimedia Gallery Special Reports



    Contact Us   Staff Directory Organization List Visit NSF Work at NSF Do Business with NSF Press Inspector General Hotline How Do I …?
    The National Science Foundation 4201 Wilson Boulevard, Arlington, Virginia 22230, USA Tel: (703) 292-5111 FIRS: (800) 877-8339 TDD: (800) 281-8749

  Home Funding
    Search Funding Opportunities Browse Opportunities A-Z Recent Opportunities Due Dates Preparing Proposals Policies & Procedures Merit Review Interdisciplinary Research Transformative Research About Funding

    Awards
    About Awards Managing Awards Policies & Procedures Award Conditions Search Awards Presidential & Honorary Awards Award Statistics (Budget Internet Info System)

    Discoveries
    Discoveries Home Arctic & Antarctic Astronomy & Space Biology Chemistry & Materials Computing Earth & Environmental Science Education
    Engineering Mathematics Nanoscience People & Society Physics Search Discoveries About Discoveries

    News
    News Home For News Media Multimedia Gallery Special Reports News from the Field Research Overviews Speeches & Lecture NSF Current Newsletter NSF-Wide Investments News Archive Search News

    Publications
    Publications Home Search Publications Obtaining Publications

    Statistics
    NCSES Home NCSES Data NCSES Publications NCSES Surveys NCSES Topics Search NCSES About NCSES

    About NSF
    About NSF History Visit NSF Contact NSF Staff Directory Organization List Career Opportunities Contracting Opportunities NSF & Congress Budget Performance Assessment Info Partners Broadening Participation/Diversity Office of Diversity & Inclusion

    Fastlane   a {

    color: #3c75cf;

    text-decoration: none;   }

    a:hover {

    background-color: #c2f96b;   }

    th {

    text-align: left;   }

    .two_liner li {

    margin-left: 20px;

    text-indent: -20px;

    list-style-type: none;   }

    .two_liner {

    margin: 0px;   }

    .block_indent {

    padding-left: 15px;   }

    .lineoff {

    text-decoration: none;   }

    .lineoff a {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #FF0000;   }

    .rightcol {

    padding: 7px;

    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: x-small;   }

    .rightimage {

    padding-bottom: 4px;   }

    .rightcol p {

    padding-bottom: 4px;   }

    .rightcol2 {

    padding: 7px;

    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: x-small;   }

    .rightcol2 a {

    text-decoration: underline;   }
```

To look at the full output, take a look at this paste:
http://pastebin.com/TMmc7Yxa

My module versions:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bs4==0.0.1
requests==2.9.1
```

OS : Windows 10 x64

Python Version : 2.x

Answer (score -1):

try importing:

```
import sys
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```